F-Statistic in MR_IVW in R
I am trying to find the F-statistic for the instrumental variables when running the mr_ivw command in R. In the help section, it states that we can get the F-statistic but actually it is not displayed. I am only getting the heterogeneity statistic:
MRObject = mr_input(bx=beta.tsh, bxse=se.tsh, by=beta, byse=standard_error)

hyperchol.ivw <-mr_ivw(MRObject)

When I look at the output, there is no F statistic.

Not on the last line?

No the last line shows me only the heterogeneity statistic.

Then something is awry with your data, which you haven't provided, so it's virtually impossible to help you further.
